# Big O measure, and deriving T(n)

Tags: big-o

I'm completely new to the area of Big O measure and T(n). For problem number one on my assignment I am trying to derive the T(n) function of the following code:

```
for (int k=3; k<n; k++) {
   for (int i=2; i<10; i++)  {
      for (int j=n/2; j<n; j++)   {
            int a = k*i*j;
            System.out.println(a);
      }
   }
 }
```

This means I have to find out the number of steps it takes to complete the function. I decided on 8 because of the middle for loop, but since I'm new to this Big O and T(n) business, I believe I'm wrong. I think it may be 10. You should give me a simple explanation for this and for solving the Big O measure for each of these functions:

```
T(n) = 3^n+3 + n^3
T(n) = nlog2n + n^3
```

If explaining this doesn't work, perhaps you should give me a website link that I can follow that offers the same good explanation I'm looking for in solving something like this. May you please help me?

Comment: what is T(n) ?? is it theta (n)?

Answer (score 0):

if T(n) means theta (n) then you are basically looking for the tight bound of the function. For this simple function you can actually just find it directly by counting.

for the j loop, it executes n/2 times ,
for the I loop it executes 10-2 times
for the k loop it executes n-3 times
so the total is (n/2) * (8) * (n-3) => T(n^2)

Comment: Yes, T(n) means theta (n)

Comment: @JordanWhite then my answer stands